# Numpy array as an input to model

Tags: python, numpy, keras, input, numpy-ndarray

I have a input to the model in the format `[train[:, :, 0:count]]` as shown below

```
n_step = 10
count = 8
def create_model():
    input = Input(shape=(n_steps, count), name='input')
    --------
    --------
    rest of the network

if __name__ == "__main__":

    model = create_model()
    history = model.fit([train[:, :, 0:count]],[y_train],epochs=50,batch_size=64,validation_data=[[val[:, :, 0:count]], y_validation])

    validationPredict = model.predict([val[:, :, 0:count]], verbose=2)
```

1st dimension is the sample, 2nd dimension is the time step, 3rd are the features(here its 8).
I have time stamp and features for each of the samples (in list). But I don't understand how to store them in a numpy array so that I can have the same format(3d) to train the network.

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: Try to be a bit more descriptive about your problem. "I have time stamp and features for each of the samples (in list)" in what format? Is all of the data stored in a single list, or are there different lists for each sample? In either case, what is the convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand - you need to convert a long 2D sequence to short sequences.

You have to create sequences of length 10:

```
n_step = 10
inp = np.random.uniform(size=(100, 20)).tolist() # long 2D sequence
labels = np.random.uniform(size=(100, )).tolist() # long 1D labels

sequences = [inp[x:x+n_step] for x in range(len(inp)-n_step)]
train = np.array(sequences) # 3D input numpy array
sequences = [labels[x:x+n_step] for x in range(len(inp)-n_step)]
y_train = np.array(sequences) # 2D labels numpy array
```